# Can not debug kaa_client_create() function

Tags: c, kaa

I'm trying to understand kaa endpoint source code, my example is "Datacollection demo".

I'm reading **kaa_client_create** function, code is below

1. in `main()`, I call **`kaa_client_create`** function like that:

   ```
   kaa_client_t *kaa_client = NULL;
   printf("[Creat kaa client] %s\n",!kaa_client? "NULL":"not NULL");
   kaa_error_t error = kaa_client_create(&kaa_client, NULL);
   printf("[Creat kaa client] %s\n",!kaa_client? "NULL":"not NULL");
   ```
2. in **`kaa_client_create`** function, I add debug line as follow:

   ```
   kaa_error_t kaa_client_create(kaa_client_t **kaa_client, kaa_client_props_t *props)
   {
       printf("I'm here \n");
       KAA_RETURN_IF_NIL2(kaa_client, props, KAA_ERR_BADPARAM);
       .....
   }
   ```
3. result in console is:

   ```
   [Creat kaa client] NULL
   [Creat kaa client] not NULL
   Default sample period: 5 seconds
   Viettq's first kaa app sampled temperature: 26
   ```

Reading the console, I think **`kaa_client_create`** function is called, because `kaa_client` doesn't point to `NULL`, but why I don't see my debug line "I'm here"?

Could you hep me to understand, what happen ?

My source code here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/obg68nmon31wdt7/kaa_myfirstproject.tar.gz?dl=0

Extract in ubuntu

```
source run_all.sh
```

Thank advance !

Viet

Comment: Have you *rebuilt* the code where `kaa_client_create` is? Have you rebuilt *your* code so it uses the newly built `kaa_client_create`?

Comment: If the code you've provided could be fashioned into a *compilable testcase* easily by filling in the blanks, don't you think it'd be better use of multiple peoples time for *you* to perform that work than to expect *all of us* to do it for you? If the code you've provided *couldn't* easily be fashioned into a *compilable testcase*, do you suppose there's enough information for us to provide a useful answer? Perhaps your problem lies elsewhere...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have rebuild it, Thank you, I attach my project below, you can try it, just extract the kaa_myfirstproject.tar.gz file on ubuntu, and run source run_all.sh.

Source code here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/obg68nmon31wdt7/kaa_myfirstproject.tar.gz?dl=0

Comment: @Seb, I'm sorry for make you angry, but it's a real problem, i have a big stuck :(, i attached my project with dropbox link as below, just extract it in ubuntu and source run_all.sh, Thank you for help me !

My project:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/obg68nmon31wdt7/kaa_myfirstproject.tar.gz?dl=0

Comment: @TrầnQuốcViệt Why do you think I'm angry? Am I yelling at you? Can you hear me yelling abusive words at a computer screen in a public library? HA HA HA HA HA HA HA HA HA HA HA HA HA HA HA HA HA HA HA HA HA HA HA HA HA HA HA HA HA HA HA HA! You're hilarious!

Comment: @Seb I think There is a big problem with my English skill :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the DropBox link does not exist any more.

But, from the code snippets you mentioned, it looks like you modified kaa_client_create() function for Econais platform which should not be used on POSIX (Linux Ubuntu as you mentioned).

If my guess is correct, you need to add the printf() to the src/kaa/platform-impl/posix/kaa_client.c file and re-build the client with that change.